# OpenCV for C++: Passing matrix using std::ref() gives a 0x0 dimension matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, oop, matrix

this is my code snippet:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numT; i++) {
    cv::Mat m2 = m1(cv::Range(get<0>(offsets[i]), get<1>(offsets[i])), cv::Range::all());
    cout << m2.rows << " " << m2.cols << endl;
    
    // start threads
    threadsVec.push_back( thread(myFunction, ref(m2)));
  }
```

I want to apply **myFunction** to subparts of the matrix in parallel. I checked the offsets and they are correct. I found out that if i print **m2's dimensions** (rows and columns) within the for it gives me the right dimensions for the matrix, while if I print it in myFunction method it gaves me 0 rows and 0 cols, what did I do wrong? How can I reach the right result?

Also, if I pass directly the entire **m1 matrix** it works correctly.

Comment: what is `m1` ? Can you provide a [mcve] ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number m1 is a cv::Mat

Comment: m2 is already out of scope and destructed when the thread starts. Not sure about OpenCV but you should declare a vector of cv::Mat outside the for loop scope to hold the m2 matrices. As you said passing m1 works because m1 is not out of scope

Comment: cv::Mats contain refcounting. you can pass them around, they all refer to the same memory. that also applies to "slices", like is done in line 2 (`m1(Range(...))`)

Comment: Thank u guys. It works declaring m2 outside the for and eliminating ref().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`m2` is destroyed at the end of your loop. Keeping a reference on it is undefined behavior.

Just pass `m2` by value instead. `cv::Mat` already behaves like a shared_ptr: copying a `cv::Mat` (and sub-matrices count as copies) won't deep-copy its internal buffer. So there's no need to use a reference on top of that.

---

Just in case, a reminder that [cv::Mat::forEach()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a952ef1a85d70a510240cb645a90efc0d) exists and allows you to apply an operation to each pixel in your matrix *in parallel* without having to bother about parallelization details. However it's limited to per-pixel operations only... so if you need to work on sub-image regions it won't do it.